# Kivy import error, module could not be found

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

Trying to use Python Kivy for the first time, pip install kivy and pygame and checked with pip freeze. When I only use "import kivy" there is no error and gives me this:

```
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\KubiK\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-02-26_50.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 28 2015, 16:44:52) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

But when I add "from kivy.app import App", it gives me this error:

```
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\KubiK\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-02-26_51.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 28 2015, 16:44:52) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\KubiK\Dropbox\Python_Exercises_KW\Kivy\BooksNTuts\AlexanderTaylor\tut.py", line 2, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "C:\Users\KubiK\AppData\Local\Dato\Dato Launcher\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 327, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
   File "C:\Users\KubiK\AppData\Local\Dato\Dato Launcher\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 219, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics import (
   File "C:\Users\KubiK\AppData\Local\Dato\Dato Launcher\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics.instructions import Callback, Canvas, CanvasBase, \
 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\KubiK\Dropbox\Python_Exercises_KW\Kivy\BooksNTuts\AlexanderTaylor\tut.py"]
```

Comment: Can you post your code and the error log?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for this [issue](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/3889). However, I'd like to suggest you using sdl2 as a provider. [This](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/KivyInstaller) could help you install it easily.